# Laravel 5.5 stripe how set short period to charge after trial period

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

When the trial period ends, stripe don't create a successful payment instantly. It only takes a few hours. This behavior makes testing difficult. Can I make this period shorter in stripe test mode?

Comment: you can try with the invoice to test whether it's working or not!  https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoice

Comment: But i see this "If you need to invoice your customer outside the regular billing cycle, you can create an invoice that pulls in all pending invoice items, including prorations. The customer’s billing cycle and regular subscription won’t be affected."   I wnan't test exactly subs and regular billing cycle. I try of course